# https iframe contents with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, https

Are there really no possibility to act on the contents of an iframe secure (https) with jquery?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iframe').load(function(){
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without violating the same-origin policy.  I get around this with [whatever-origin.](http://www.whateverorigin.org)